# Firefox - Allowing file:// protocol

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-11, protocol

I'm actually struggling allowing `file://` protocol on my intranet.

I tried :

- Setting `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` to `false`.
- An extension named "LocalLink" ;
  not accept my version of firefox (which is the last one) ;
- Modifying my link like `file://///`, with more or less /.

If anyone has any kind of tricks to allow this, it'll be perfect.

Regards.

Comment: is this a link on a webpage or are you typing it in?

Comment: A link on a webpage, but I finally managed to set the right policy. I misunderstood the wiki page on mozillazine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I just misread [Mozillazine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_Issues_:_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don't_Work) and thought it was no more possible in newer browsers.

In fact, just edit :

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<Windows login>\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile folder>\prefs.js
```

In this file, add the following preferences :

```
user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "localfilelinks");
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.sites", "http://A.B.C.D/");
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.checkloaduri.enabled", "allAccess");
```

All file:// link on the specified sites will now be clickable.